# How to make an enemy in a tower defence game follow waypoints and deal with 2 direction options in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I am trying to make a tower defence game and I have a system for making the enemies follow a set of waypoints from the start to the end. However, this doesn't work with a fork in the path, as below:

[image: Tower Defence Game Path Split Screenshot]

I am currently just having them work through an array of waypoints, but how would I change this to allow some to go on the top path and some to go on the bottom one? I would preferably be looking to be able to add more than 1 split in later levels.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make multiple sets of waypoints and assign enemys to them.
Make index in enemy spawning system and odd numbered enemy assign to route 1, even numbered enemy assign to route 2 for example.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm quite new to Unity so how would I have a script in each route GameObject to create a Waypoints array but that doesn't override the array of the other route(s)? And how would I address each of those?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this post, Instead of having different set of waypoints, for every forked path you can have a special waypoint called decision waypoint, which can hold reference to the two or more waypoints that lead to the respective paths. When enemy ai hits this speacial waypoint it can choose(decide)the next waypoint that will move it on the corresponding path.
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).